# Mcrypt issue when passing from URL to URL

Tags: php, encryption, obfuscation, mcrypt

Hello i'm using Mcrypt to obfuscate some values i'm sending via mail.

When i encrypt the value on my local site, and decrypt it it works ok in every attempt, i mail the value, but when i link back to my site, and try to decrypt it in another page, it works sometimes only.

I'm kinda stuck and dunno why. I'm not so familiar with crypt functions.

This is the code im using for **encrypt**

```
function encrypt($decrypted, $password, $salt='!kQm*fF3pXe1Kbm%9') { 
 // Build a 256-bit $key which is a SHA256 hash of $salt and $password.
 $key = hash('SHA256', $salt . $password, true);
 // Build $iv and $iv_base64.  We use a block size of 128 bits (AES compliant) and CBC mode.  (Note: ECB mode is inadequate as IV is not used.)
 srand(); $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
 if (strlen($iv_base64 = rtrim(base64_encode($iv), '=')) != 22) return false;
 // Encrypt $decrypted and an MD5 of $decrypted using $key.  MD5 is fine to use here because it's just to verify successful decryption.
 $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $decrypted . md5($decrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
 // We're done!
 return $iv_base64 . $encrypted;
 }
```

This is the code i'm using for **decrypt**

```
function decrypt($encrypted, $password, $salt='!kQm*fF3pXe1Kbm%9') {
 // Build a 256-bit $key which is a SHA256 hash of $salt and $password.
 $key = hash('SHA256', $salt . $password, true);
 // Retrieve $iv which is the first 22 characters plus ==, base64_decoded.
 $iv = base64_decode(substr($encrypted, 0, 22) . '==');
 // Remove $iv from $encrypted.
 $encrypted = substr($encrypted, 22);
 // Decrypt the data.  rtrim won't corrupt the data because the last 32 characters are the md5 hash; thus any \0 character has to be padding.
 $decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv), "\0\4");
 // Retrieve $hash which is the last 32 characters of $decrypted.
 $hash = substr($decrypted, -32);
 // Remove the last 32 characters from $decrypted.
 $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -32);
 // Integrity check.  If this fails, either the data is corrupted, or the password/salt was incorrect.
 if (md5($decrypted) != $hash) return false;
 // Yay!
 return $decrypted;
 }
```

The `$password` and `$salt` variables are being packed using

```
pack("H*", $string);
```

After the first failed attempts, i started using `urlencode` and `urldecode` for the values on the URL but still the same issue persists.

What i'm doing wrong? i'm really stuck here

Thanks

Comment: You're already doing a `base64_encode`, you don't too URLencode those value (you can but it doesn't do anything). What's up with those seemingly aribtrary `substr` and `trim`s?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen on my edit is the original code with comments

Comment: `trim` here is not used to remove spaces. If you supply a second argument it will trim those characters. But I guess it's fine. See if you can find something in the email that messes up the URLs.

Comment: Nothing, i changed my tests without email and just send the values to another page, the encrypted string i'm passing is equal in both sides, but the decrypt function will just not work sometimes.

Comment: Is it possible that the encrypt/decrypt just doesn't work sometimes _regardless_ of whether you email it or not? If that's the case my guess the problem is in one of those funky `trim`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your encoded string is being sent with plus (+) signs, wich are being interpreted on the url as blank spaces, you can encode the URL or use str_replace to change empty spaces on the string for plus's sign

Such.

```
$encrypted_string= "random1234string with blank space";
$empty = array(" ");
$plus   = array("+");

$new_encrypted_string = str_replace($empty, $plus, $encrypted_string);
```

**Outputs**: "random1234string+with+blank+space"